# Is there a triangle in a complete graph with 6 vertices, and all edges colored with 2 colors?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have complete graph of 6 vertices. I want to prove that if we color all the edges with 2 colors, there must be a triangle of one of the colors.

I see that there are $15$ edges, the degree of each vertex is $5$. I want to prove that there isn't a circle of $3$ vertices, but I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Pick a vertex. Show that there are at least three edges of a color, call it color 1.

Now look at the triangle made by the three end vertices of those edges.
What happens if one edge is of color 1? What happens if no edge is of color 1?

Comment: So it's not too much combinatorical problem as simply logical. Because show that there are 3 edges of a color is trivial as for any two amount of edges from the same vertex, one of the amount must be at least 3, even by simple number trying. 0+5, 1+4, 2+3 if we look at degree of each vertex of each color knowing that the sum of that degrees is 5, right?